# Laravel 5.3 soft deletes not working when defining a constructor for the model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model

I have a model Test as follows

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class Test extends Model
{
use SoftDeletes;
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
public function __construct() {
    if (!\App::environment('production')) {
        $this->table='test_stage';
    }
}
```

I have made sure that there is a 'deleted_at' column in my test_stage table. But the soft deletes are not working. Using the delete() method permanently removes  the record from the table. As an additional step of verification I manually added 'deleted_at' value for some columns. But query the model still gives me the soft deleted record.

Moreover, removing the model constructor entirely and simply defining the table name using:

```
protected $table = 'test_stage';
```

Works like a charm! That is soft deletes magically start working again.

Or is there any way around to define the table name according to the environment without the need of defining a constructor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem could be that you're overwriting the constructor, which is set in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`. Have you tried

```
   public function __construct(array $attributes = []) {
       parent::__construct($attributes);
       if (!\App::environment('production')) {
           $this->table='test_stage';
       }
   }
```

**Edit:** more detailed explaination

As you overwrite the `constructor` of the class you're extending, the original does not get executed anymore. This means necessary functions for the eloquent model do not get executed. See the `constructor` for  `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` below:

```
/**
 * Create a new Eloquent model instance.
 *
 * @param  array  $attributes
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    $this->bootIfNotBooted();

    $this->syncOriginal();

    $this->fill($attributes);
}
```

By making sure the **extending** class requires the same parameters for the constructor as the **extended class** and executes  `parent::__construct($attributes);` first, the `constructor` of the **extended** class gets executed first. After which you can overwrite `$this->table` in the **extending class**.

Comment: @RafaelBerro Updated. Hope my answer is clearer now.

Comment: @Stormhammer Woow! Thats exactly what was happening. I was suspicious about a similar thing but missed the right direction.